# How to Schedule multiple Flux in parallel and limit onNext and onRequest Events

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to combine multiple `Flux` of the same type together. At the time of subscription they should be executed in parallel. The subscribing method should be able to limit the number of requests.

I experimented with `Flux.merge(..)` and `Flux.concat(..)`. The later seems to enforce a sequential request production even when publishing on a parallel scheduler when the first requests all elements in a eager way and only respects the `take(n)` Method for the `onNext` Events but not for the `onRequest` Events.

I prepared a minimal example. Three `Flux` which shall all execute heavy i/o work on a `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`. Each logging their `onRequest` Event.

```
Flux<String> f1 = Flux.just("1").publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).flatMap(i -> {
    try {
        //Long running, i/o task
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Flux.just(i);
}).doOnRequest(s -> LOGGER.info("onRequest {}", 1));
Flux<String> f2 = Flux.just("2").publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).flatMap(i -> {
    try {
        //Long running, i/o task
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Flux.just(i);
}).doOnRequest(s -> LOGGER.info("onRequest {}", 2));
Flux<String> f3 = Flux.just("3").publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).flatMap(i -> {
    try {
        //Long running, i/o task
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Flux.just(i);
}).doOnRequest(s -> LOGGER.info("onRequest {}", 3));
```

### Approach with with `Flux.concat` and `take(2)`

```
Flux.concat(f1, f2, f3).take(2)
        .doOnNext(i -> LOGGER.info("onNext {}", i))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).subscribe();
```

**Result:**

```
00:16:11.980   [oundedElastic-1] d.f.B.Application                        : onRequest 1
00:16:13.981   [oundedElastic-2] d.f.B.Application                        : onNext 1
00:16:13.981   [oundedElastic-2] d.f.B.Application                        : onRequest 2
00:16:15.982   [oundedElastic-3] d.f.B.Application                        : onNext 2
```

Two `onRequest` and two `onNext` Events are propagated. The requests are delayed by two seconds **but where expected parallel**.

### Approach with `Flux.map` and `take(2)`

```
Flux.merge(f1, f2, f3).take(2)
        .doOnNext(i -> LOGGER.info("onNext {}", i))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).subscribe();
```

**Result**

```
00:21:58.301   [oundedElastic-1] d.f.B.Application                        : onRequest 1
00:21:58.302   [oundedElastic-1] d.f.B.Application                        : onRequest 2
00:21:58.302   [oundedElastic-1] d.f.B.Application                        : onRequest 3
00:22:00.303   [oundedElastic-4] d.f.B.Application                        : onNext 3
00:22:00.304   [oundedElastic-3] d.f.B.Application                        : onNext 2
```

**Three** `onRequest` **events are emitted even though only two where expected**. The `take(n)` method just limited the emitted `onNext` events. The execution was done parallel as expected.

### Expected Result for unknown approach

```
00:21:58.302   [oundedElastic-1] d.f.B.Application                        : onRequest 2
00:21:58.302   [oundedElastic-1] d.f.B.Application                        : onRequest 3
00:22:00.303   [oundedElastic-4] d.f.B.Application                        : onNext 3
00:22:00.304   [oundedElastic-3] d.f.B.Application                        : onNext 2
```

Only two `onRequest` events are emitted and completed

### Question

Is it possible to combine these three `Flux` in a way where they can be computed simultaneous but limited (`take(n)`?)in their request behaviour? In my real-world-scenario a request results in a WebClient calling a WebService, starting a time consuming i/o task. So even though my application is just recieving two onNext events, the third emitted onRequest results in a request that goes into nirvana.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Also can you post the actual problem you are trying to solve. This looks like it could possibly be an X -> Y issue.

Comment: I am experimenting with the reactive programming approach, so I want to learn it. I updated my question with an expected output.

Comment: I can't think of a situation where this would be useful though, is there a real problem, or you just want to know if you can do this? Also in your expected result would you not expect 1,2 1,2 not 2,3 3,2

Comment: I don't need to solve this problem to get a solution for my real problem since I could also create a `Flux<String>` for each API with their own limit and subscribe them one after another. But this is more a matter of my interest if I have a valid problem to solve or if I misunderstand some of the concepts in project reactor.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to project-reactor as well, but I came up with this workaround that some might call a hack:

```
Flux.fromIterable(Lists.partition(Arrays.asList(f1, f2, f3), 2))
        .take(1)
        .flatMap(partition -> Flux.merge(partition)
                .doOnNext(i -> LOGGER.info("onNext {}", i)))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .subscribe();
```

It printed out this for me:

```
2020-04-17 01:07:37.658  INFO 59488 --- [oundedElastic-1] com.example.demo.SomeService1            : onRequest 1
2020-04-17 01:07:37.659  INFO 59488 --- [oundedElastic-1] com.example.demo.SomeService1            : onRequest 2
2020-04-17 01:07:39.664  INFO 59488 --- [oundedElastic-3] com.example.demo.SomeService1            : onNext 2
2020-04-17 01:07:39.667  INFO 59488 --- [oundedElastic-2] com.example.demo.SomeService1            : onNext 1
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your approach. In your first line you are dividing the list into sub-lists with a maximum size of two. So taking one will work in this szenario. But your approach does also work, if you divide into a size of 1. So the take() method can define how much requests are emitted.
Unfortunately I would like to find a reactive-version for this problem.

Comment: I get the feeling that the `doOnRequest` method was designed for a different purpose. 

If you only want something to be executed every time an element is emitted then, you should probably use a lazy (cold) publisher using `Mono.fromCallable(() -> heavyIoOperation())`.

In case you want it be done only when the first element is emitted, you could keep track of whether it has been emitted or not by using a boolean. For instance, you could do:

`Mono.fromCallable(() -> myBoolean).filter(b -> b).switchIfEmpty(() -> heavyIoOperation())`

Comment: In my real-case I create a Flux of consecutive `WebClient` calls that traverse the API. I figured out, that a GET-Request seems to be emitted on each doOnRequest events. So I thought it would be good for a minimal example since my issue is, that more GET-Requests are emitted than expected. I need to take a look into your example with `Mono.fromCallable(..)`. I had a similar idea using `Mono.defer(..)` but unfortunately it did not recognize any improvement.